# Improving the rendering performance in drawing heat map

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to draw a heat map with a given input of points and amplitude of each point. The normal input size is around 400,000 points, but the code draws every 15<sup>th</sup> point. The map is drawn onto a `Canvas`.

In the XAML:

```xaml
<Grid x:Name="MainPanel" Width="800" Height="600">
    <Textbox Name="textbox" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Canvas Name="canvas" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="450" Margin="70,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="706"/>
</Grid>
```

Rendering code:

```
public static void DrawPoints(Parser parser, Canvas canvas, double radiusX, double radiusY, double thickness, double minAmplitude, double maxAmplitude)
{
    double cellWidth = canvas.ActualWidth;
    double cellHeight = canvas.ActualHeight;

    var list = parser.Data;

    // Draws every 15th point
    int res = 15;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i += res)
    {
        var location = list[i].Point;
        var amplitude = list[i].Amplitude;

        // Converts rgb to hsv values for representation
        var color= ColorConverter.hsv2rgb(
            COLOR_START_H * (1.0 - ((amplitude - minAmplitude) / (maxAmplitude - minAmplitude))),
            COLOR_START_S, COLOR_START_V);

        Point center = new Point(location.X, location.Y);
        DrawEllipse(canvas, center, radiusX, radiusY,
            new SolidColorBrush(color), new SolidColorBrush(color), thickness);
    }
    return;
}
```

In the `DrawEllipse` function:

```
public static void DrawEllipse(Canvas canvas, Point center, double radiusX, double radiusY, Brush fill, Brush stroke, double thickness)
{
    var ellipse = new Ellipse();
    ellipse.Width = radiusX * 2;
    ellipse.Height = radiusY * 2;
    ellipse.Fill = fill;
    ellipse.Stroke = stroke;
    ellipse.StrokeThickness = thickness;

    Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, center.X - radiusX);
    Canvas.SetBottom(ellipse, center.Y - radiusY);

    canvas.Children.Add(ellipse);

    return;
}
```

In the Main code:

```
private void btnDraw_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Painter.DrawPoints(parser, canvas, 3, 3, 1, 0, 100);
}
```

The issue is that after rendering all the points onto `Canvas`, when I try to enter some text into `textbox` within the same grid, there is significant lag. What can I do to reduce the lag?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the WriteableBitmapEx library.

Comment: Does the data change or do you only need to generate it once? Do you need interactivity (context menu, tooltips, zoom) or would a snapshot / image (as suggested by Clemens) suffice?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer It will need to be generated once only. The only interactivity is `onMouseClick`, where it will return the value of the amplitude at the point of the click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, is draw all of your data into a `Visual` and render it with a `RenderTargetBitmap`. This will take a while but will solve your performance-issues.

```
private List<Point> _points;
private Size _targetarea;

private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _targetarea = new Size(500, 500);
    _points = GeneratePoints(10000, _targetarea);
    TheImage.Source = DrawPoints(_points, _targetarea, 5, 5, 1);
}

private List<Point> GeneratePoints(int count, Size size)
{
    Random r = new Random();

    return Enumerable.Range(0, count)
        .Select(j => new Point(r.NextDouble() * size.Width, r.NextDouble() * size.Height))
        .ToList();
}

private static ImageSource DrawPoints(IEnumerable<Point> points, Size size, double radiusX, double radiusY, double thickness)
{
    DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();

    using (DrawingContext context = visual.RenderOpen())
    {
        var fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
        var stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

        foreach(var center in points)
        {
            context.DrawEllipse(fill, new Pen(stroke, thickness), center, radiusX, radiusY);
        }
    }

    RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    bitmap.Render(visual);
    bitmap.Freeze();
    return bitmap;
}
```

To determine the nearest data point when you click on the image, simply use the original data that you used to generate the image.

```
private void TheImage_OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point clickPoint = GetCoordinates(e.GetPosition((IInputElement) sender));

    Point closestPoint = new Point();
    double minSquareDistance = double.MaxValue;

    foreach (Point point in _points)
    {
        double dX = point.X - clickPoint.X;
        double dY = point.Y - clickPoint.Y;
        double squareDistance = dX * dX * dY * dY;
        if (squareDistance < minSquareDistance)
        {
            minSquareDistance = squareDistance;
            closestPoint = point;
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show($"Clicked near {closestPoint.X:f0}/{closestPoint.Y:f0}");
}

private Point GetCoordinates(Point position)
{
    // Here you need to translate Screen-Coordinates to your internal coordinate system
    return position;
}
```

---

To speed up the process, install `WriteableBitmapEx` (NuGet available) and use this instead:

```
private static ImageSource DrawPoints(IEnumerable<Point> points, Size size, double radiusX, double radiusY, double thickness)
{
    WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32, null);

    foreach(var center in points)
    {
        bitmap.FillEllipse((int)(center.X - radiusX), (int)(center.Y - radiusY), (int)(center.X + radiusX), (int)(center.Y + radiusY), Colors.Yellow);
        bitmap.DrawEllipse((int) (center.X - radiusX), (int) (center.Y - radiusY), (int) (center.X + radiusX), (int) (center.Y + radiusY), Colors.Red);
    }

    bitmap.Freeze();
    return bitmap;
}
```

---

I don't have access to the rest of your code, so the following code is using a lot of simplifications and random data e.g. I'm using an `Image` instead of a `Canvas` and simple `Point`s instead of whatever your parser returns.

Comment: Thanks this solves the issue of the GUI lag, but i realised with this method of rendering, it is actually much slower than drawing directly on the canvas. Are there any tips to help speed up the performance?

Comment: @JohnTan You could pre-render portions of the heat map (sorted by z-order) in multiple threads and then merge them all together with the same method. Since `bitmap.Freeze()` makes sure the resulting image is thread-safe (and locked) so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: How would I do that? Is the idea something like passing `context` into different threads, with each thread running `context.DrawEllipse()`? If so, how would I merge all of them together again?

Comment: Oh, no that's not what I meant. I meant passing portions of your data to a couple of threads, they all create a separate image and then you merge (overlay) the images with `context.DrawImage` on a new DrawingVisual. Another option would be to use 3rd party libraries that are faster at drawing to an image (I don't know any but I'm sure they exist).

Comment: @JohnTan `WriteableBitmapEx` (Clemes mentioned it in the comments) works brilliantly - I've update the answer (at the bottom).

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly now without any lag. Personally I just wonder at what sort of tricks that they use within the same framework that achieves this.